# Angular Cli - Dojo module not found

Tags: angular, dojo, arcgis, typescript-typings, esri

I am developing an angular application with Argis 4.8 JS api. I need the Dojo / On function. I do not get an error in the compiler either. But when I compile, I get the error "Module not found: Error: Can not resolve 'dojo / on' path". I can not use the Dojo class. What should I do?

My full code

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {loadModules} from 'esri-loader';
import esri = __esri;
import on = require('dojo/on');


function executeIdentifyTask(event: Event | undefined) {
  console.log(event);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-esri-map',
  templateUrl: './esri-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./esri-map.component.css']
})

export class EsriMapComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('mapViewNode') private mapViewEl: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  map: esri.Map;
  mapView: esri.MapView;
  layer: esri.MapImageLayer;
  identifyTask: esri.IdentifyTask;

  async initializeMap() {

    try {
      const [EsriMap, EsriMapView, MapImageLayer, IdentifyTask, IdentifyTaskProperties] = await loadModules([
        'esri/Map',
        'esri/views/MapView',
        'esri/layers/MapImageLayer',
        'esri/tasks/IdentifyTask',
        'esri/tasks/support/IdentifyParameters'
      ]);


      this.map = new EsriMap({
        basemap: 'dark-gray'
      });


      this.mapView = new EsriMapView({
        container: this.mapViewEl.nativeElement,
        center: [27.1428, 38.4237],
        zoom: 15,
        map: this.map
      });

      this.layer = new MapImageLayer(
        {url: 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer'});

      this.map.add(this.layer);
      this.mapView.when(function () {
        on(this.mapView , 'click' , executeIdentifyTask);
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('We have an error: ' + error);
    }

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeMap();
  }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to import it like `import { on }  from 'dojo'` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I got this error.
TS2305: Module '"dojo/on"' has no exported member 'on'.

Comment: can you please try the same after installing `dojo typings` module instead of using reference `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/dojo/index.d.ts" />`?

Comment: I installed the module. The compiler does not seem to have a problem either. I can also go to the function when I press the F12 key. But I get an error when compiled.

Comment: try adding as `.js` in `script` tag in `index.html`

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no solution. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I am a bit late to the party, but for anyone else having a similar issue, I find that these errors that are described as ones where you can press the F12 key and find the type, but fail to compile correctly, are usually caused by not putting the type within the `types: []` array within the `tsconfig.app.json`.

I experienced a similar issue with the `__esri` import and kept receiving the following err `ERROR in src/app/esri-map/esri-map.component.ts(16,15): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace '__esri'.` and upon adding `"arcgis-js-api"` to my `tsconfig.app.json`, my problem was resolved.